# Ranges from RangeOfRanges

Tags: d

In D you can do the following to create pair wise tuples of array elements:

```
auto a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
auto x = a.zip(a.save.dropOne);
```

`x` can now be expanded to `[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`.

I would like to generalize this concept to create n-tuples like this:

```
auto i = 0;
auto x = zip(generate!(() => a.save.dropExactly(i++)).take(n));
```

However, this leads to `x` being a range of `Tuple!([1, 2, 3, 4]), Tuple!([2, 3, 4])` for n = 2.

This is plausible, since `take` produces subranges. But how can I create separate ranges to achieve the intended behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give an example of the 'intended behavior'? I don't understand the question.

Comment: For n=2 I would like to be able to expand `x` to `[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]` using `generate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like [`slide`](https://github.com/dlang/phobos/blob/master/std/range/package.d#L7814). It's already part of Phobos and will be included in the next release (2.076.0):

```d
assert([0, 1, 2, 3].slide(2).equal!equal(
    [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
));
assert(5.iota.slide(3).equal!equal(
    [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
));
```

However, note that for random access ranges it's easy to achieve a sliding window iterator out of the box:

```d
import std.range, std.stdio;
void main(string[] args)
{
    auto arr = 5.iota;
    auto n = 2;
    // Plain D arrays & slices
    foreach (i; 0 .. arr.length - n + 1)
        arr[i .. i + n].writeln;
    // [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]

    // As a range
    arr = 10.iota;
    n = 3;
    int k = 0;
    generate!(() => arr[k .. k++ + n]).take(3).writeln;
    // [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]

    n = 4, k = 0;
    generate!(() => arr[k .. k++ + n]).take(3).writeln;
    // [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]]
}
```

[Play with this example online](https://run.dlang.io/gist/0b9678a410faa2589e42f288cda8646b?compiler=dmd).

Comment: The `generate` is almost working: `generate!(() => arr[k .. min(k++ + n, arr.length)]).take(3).writeln;` also works if you `take` all possible subranges.

Comment: Well as mentioned - it depends on what you want to achieve.If you can clarify this, helping you will be easier ;-)

Comment: You will get a range violation if the end of the slice is not limited.

Comment: What happened to slide in 2.076.0? Was it released? I cannot find it on dlang.org.

Comment: Unfortunately due to last minute complications its release has been delayed, but it's already in std/range.d (in case you want to copy/paste it to your project).